# Is there a way to load llvm bitcode into Mono (F#)

Tags: f#, mono, llvm

LLVM has libraries that allow easy reading and writing of bitcode. This enables e.g. writing code generators that output llvm bitcode (which one can compile to native code using llvm), or loading bitcode files and performing optimizations or analyses on them.

One can even do so from OCaml.

Is there a library to load LLVM bitcode into Mono (F#), and browse it as e.g. an object tree?

(Note: I do not want to execute LLVM bitcode in Mono, just load the code and browse the structures.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[llvm-fs](https://github.com/fsharp/llvm-fs)** is a set of F# bindings for the LLVM project.

**Bonus reading:**

- [Building a simple compiler with F# and LLVM on windows.](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-llvm-from-f-under-windows.html)